# How can I put a horizontal scroll bar in this table?

Tags: table, scrolling, lighting-web-component

When I try to view the mobile version of this table, I don't get the horizontal scroll bar. What should I do to view the scroll bar or make it responsive? I already tried to add:

```
<div class="slds-scrollable" style="height:5rem;width:24rem">
  <div class="slds-text-longform" style="width:150%">
```

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups/#Grouped

```
<div class="demo-only" style="height:640px">
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse">
                <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">
                    <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
                </svg>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel and close</span>
            </button>
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <h1 class="slds-text-heading_medium">Account name</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <div class="slds-lookup" data-select="multi" data-scope="single" data-typeahead="true">
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-p-top_medium slds-p-horizontal_medium slds-m-bottom_small">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="lookup">Accounts</label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
                                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <input type="text" id="lookup" class="slds-input" role="combobox" aria-activedescendant=""
                                aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="lookup-grouped-table-id-1"
                                aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="slds-scrollable" style="height:5rem;width:24rem">
                   <div class="slds-text-longform" style="width:150%">
                    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover"
                        role="listbox" id="lookup-grouped-table-id-1"
                        aria-label="Example table for advanced modal lookup">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colSpan="4" scope="col">
                                    <div class="slds-float_right">
                                        <button
                                            class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-x-small"
                                            title="Filter List">
                                            <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                                                <use
                                                    xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#filterList">
                                                </use>
                                            </svg>
                                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Filter List</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <button
                                            class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-x-small"
                                            title="Sort">
                                            <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                                                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#sort">
                                                </use>
                                            </svg>
                                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>5 Results, sorted by relevancy
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Location">Location</div>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Secondary Column">Secondary Column</div>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Tertiary Column">Tertiary Column</div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <a id="s01" href="#" role="option">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Acme Landscape">
                                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-standard-account slds-icon_small slds-m-right_x-small"
                                                aria-hidden="true">
                                                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account">
                                                </use>
                                            </svg>Acme Landscape
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Seattle, WA">Seattle, WA</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Secondary Field">Secondary Field</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Tertiary Field">Tertiary Field</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <a id="s02" href="#" role="option">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="ACME Construction">
                                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-standard-account slds-icon_small slds-m-right_x-small"
                                                aria-hidden="true">
                                                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account">
                                                </use>
                                            </svg>ACME Construction
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="San Francisco, CA">San Francisco, CA</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Secondary Field">Secondary Field</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Tertiary Field">Tertiary Field</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <a id="s03" href="#" role="option">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Action Sports">
                                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-standard-account slds-icon_small slds-m-right_x-small"
                                                aria-hidden="true">
                                                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account">
                                                </use>
                                            </svg>Action Sports
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Madison, WI">Madison, WI</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Secondary Field">Secondary Field</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Tertiary Field">Tertiary Field</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <a id="s04" href="#" role="option">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Moderno Bistro">
                                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-standard-account slds-icon_small slds-m-right_x-small"
                                                aria-hidden="true">
                                                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account">
                                                </use>
                                            </svg>Moderno Bistro
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Acton, OH">Acton, OH</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Secondary Field">Secondary Field</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Tertiary Field">Tertiary Field</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <a id="s05" href="#" role="option">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cozy Kitchen">
                                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-standard-account slds-icon_small slds-m-right_x-small"
                                                aria-hidden="true">
                                                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account">
                                                </use>
                                            </svg>Cozy Kitchen
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Acton, CA">Acton, CA</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Secondary Field">Secondary Field</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Tertiary Field">Tertiary Field</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer slds-modal__footer_directional">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" aria-label="Cancel and close">Cancel</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">New Account</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lines of code that you say you tried should have been sufficient. They create a bounding box of 24rem, and a content box of 150% of that width, forcing the scroll with style class slds-scrollable.

I can't see where you placed those lines, though, so I can't say for certain what should have happened.

You can try using the style class slds-scrollable_x instead. This should force the x-axis scrollbar to appear, and it will be grayed out if the content fits. That will at least let you know if your content needs scrolling or not. You may simply not be overflowing your bounds.

Edit: I had slds-scrollable_x wrong. I had thought it comparable to overflow-x: scroll, but it's actually overflow-x: auto, overflow-y: hidden;. So to do what I suggested, use style="overflow-x: scroll;" instead of the class.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I edited the question and I placed those lines in the code.  I put before `<table>` tag

Comment: A tried before <tbody> too, but i'm recieving `<div> has no matching closing tag`

Comment: Update: It works putting  `style="overflow-x: scroll"` in  `<div class="slds-modal__content" id="modal-content-id-1">`. Thanks!!!!